# Set social metadata for URL

Tags: javascript, firebase, metadata, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I created a url-shortener ( it's basically a simple redirection from the original url to the new url ), now i want to associate some social metadata to the short url(the new url)

I wanted to know is there any JS tool that allows me to do this so when i copy paste the short url on social media app like facebook or twitter i get a preview for my link ( like firebase dynamic links works [firebase dynamic links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/link-previews))

Comment: Unless you take explicit steps against it, the social networks should get that info from the target URL by themselves already. Their scraper/crawlers will realize that your URL just does a redirect to the final target.

Comment: yes it's already displaying the metadata of the original URL ! but i want it to display my personal metadata  like firebase dynamic links does  !

Comment: Well then you need to make your own URL not redirect, but return an HTML document containing the appropriate meta data, when it gets requested by one of those scrapers. (The Facebook scraper can be recognized by its user agent, other networks probably provide a similar means to identify theirs.)